# How to fix VM issue with minikube start ?

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, devops, minikube

I am a beginner to Kubernetes and starting off with [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-your-node-js-application) tutorial. I installed [VM](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and expected to be able to start a cluster by using the command:

```
minikube start
```

But I get the error:

```
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0911 13:34:45.394430   41676 start.go:174] Error starting host: Error 
creating host: Error executing step: Creating VM.
: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only 
adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known 
VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least 
version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue.
```

It says that it is a well known bug in Virtualbox but I installed its latest version. Any ideas?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Figured out the issue. VirtualBox was not installed correctly as Mac had blocked it. It wasn't obvious at first.

- Restarting won't work if VirtualBox isn't installed correctly.
- System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Allow -> Then allow the software corporation (in this case Oracle)
- Restart

Now it worked as expected.

Comment: I don't see any option for 'Allow'

Comment: If you don't see "Allow" option or even after multiple restarts also if it didn't worked then try to update vmware then follow above steps it will work.it worked for me with VirtualBox-6.0.10-132072-OSX.dmg version

Comment: If you don't see "Allow," make sure you're in the "General" tab of Security & Privacy, not any of the other three.

Comment: Using OSX 10.15.6 (catalina) and VirtualBox 6.1.12, I had to use System Preferences, Security and Privacy, General to allow Oracle ("Allow apps downloaded from: App Store and identified developers").  Then I removed and reinstalled VirtualBox.  Also try starting a VM from the VirtualBox GUI, that discovered two other permissions that it required.

Comment: This stack overflow page is linked to from the failed output of `minikube start`, but I'd like to point out that running minikube start on kernel 5.8 of fedora core 32 breaks this way too. Going back to kernel 5.7.x fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Thanks , working for me, validated at Mac OS Catalina with VirtualBox-6.1.14

Comment: I second the comment above. This worked for me too. I didn't see the allow button at first, either. After I clicked the uninstall tool that VirtualBox provided, I saw a button on the general tab under security and privacy. Then I installed 6.1.14 again, and the allow button was present on the General tab, and everything worked from there!

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried restarting your computer after installing the VirtualBox ?
(seems to be also a known bug to [docker-machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4066) which is used by minikube to initialize you local env)

Answer (score 4):

This definitely worked for me, starting minikube by specifying vm-driver and kubernetes-version

> minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit --kubernetes-version v1.16.0

Comment: Be aware that this above command is not using a virtualbox driver. Hyperkit is a whole different beast on it's own, with it's own set of features and issues.

Comment: virtual box and docker driver don't work for me on macOS 12.6 intel. hyperkit works!

Answer (score 4):

Faced a similar issue in Mac after upgrading to big sur. The running minikube instance started giving the same error.

The solution that worked for me was to run a **minikube delete**, followed by a **minikube start**.

More combination of this option can be found in the thread below -

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3614

Answer (score 0):

If you are in macOS 13+ VirtualBox will not work so you can use docker instead.

#### Usage

Start a cluster using the docker driver:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

To make docker the default driver:

```
minikube config set driver docker
```