# Impossible to start Minikube on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, minikube, macos-ventura

After upgrading my macOS to Ventura I can't start Minikube.

```
  Failed to start virtualbox VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: creating: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue

❌  Exiting due to IF_VBOX_NOT_VISIBLE: Failed to start host: creating host: create: creating: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
  Suggestion: Reboot to complete VirtualBox installation, verify that VirtualBox is not blocked by your system, and/or use another hypervisor
  Documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277019/how-to-fix-vm-issue-with-minikube-start
  Related issues:
    ▪ https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3614
    ▪ https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4222
    ▪ https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5817
```

I'm using Minikube v 1.28 and virtualbox 7.0.4

Any idea if I can still using that virtualbox version on macOS Ventura?

Comment: Did you try doing what the error says?

Comment: @Julia yeap. Didn't work.

Comment: Uninstalling VBox with the `VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool`  fixed it in my case because it automatically chose the vmware driver :p

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following steps will resolve your issue starting Minikube:

1. minikube delete --purge --all
2. minikube start --driver=virtualbox

Comment: i am trying this and I get:

Exiting due to DRV_UNSUPPORTED_OS: The driver 'virtualbox' is not supported on darwin/arm64

Comment: Didn't work for me in Ventura. Same error as the OP's.